# Connecting Visual Studio 2015 Community to SQL server Express 2016

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've got SQL server 2016 Express and Visual Studio 2015 community.   In SQL Server management studio, I can access SQL server and create databases, tables, etc. When I try to add a connection to the database from VS I can see the Server name (the name of my computer) but when I click "Test connection" it reports an error

"    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
    The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
    (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)"

I've gone into SQL server configuration manager and enabled Named Pipes and TCP/IP, I've tried turning off the firewall, I've uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and SQL server, I've deleted SQLAGENT.OUT and I've turned it off and on again.   In computer management I've noticed that "SQL server agent(SQLEXPRESS)" is stopped and won't start, when I try to start it it times out and event viewer says
"SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: This installation of SQL Server Agent is disabled.  The edition of SQL Server that installed this service does not support SQL Server Agent.)."

I've checked the SQL Server service and that's using the 
NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
account to log on. the corresponding entry in the databases Logins list has server tole of "public" and "sysadmin"

That's everything I can find via Google, anyone have any other ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The instance name to connect to is `.\SQLEXPRESS`. Are you using that in VS? (SQL Server Agent won't run on Express, that's normal and of no concern.)

Comment: Note that if you're not sharing the instance with multiple users, a simpler alternative is to use LocalDB. A default instance of `(localdb)\MSSqlLocalDB` is created out of the box.

Comment: The "Server name" was "(computername)" which was the only option in the drop down so I foolishly trusted it, using ".\SQLEXPRESS" instead shows all the databases and "Test connection" works.    When I try to connect I get the error "Unable to add data connection Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its dependencies"   Every time I get passed on hurdle another appears :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this, I solved the second "Unable to add data connection problem" by following the instructions here

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/0d25df29-0d2b-4b57-8807-392a379c1dc3?category=visualstudiogeneral

Which basically says, do a modify of Visual Studio's installation by adding "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools"
Then I did a repair installation which highlit a problem with "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.something" and the x86 version as they were newer than the ones it was trying to repair to.   So I uninstalled them and reran repair.   Seems to be working now.